Python argparse with bash alias
I have the following bash script that I source in my root directory:
ROOT_DIR="$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
eval "$(register-python-argcomplete ${ROOT_DIR}/bin/execute.py)"

The execute.py file has Python autocompletion enabled and it works perfectly when I use the full path to my script in the bash shell:
/absolute/path/to/root/bin/execute.py <Tab>   # This works perfectly

Now I want to create an alias, say my_command, so that I don't have to provide the full path. I want to use just:
my_command <Tab>

I've tried creating a simple bash alias:
alias my_command="${ROOT_DIR}/bin/execute.py"

or a function:
my_command() {
    ${ROOT_DIR}/bin/execute.py "$@"
}

but neither of them works. Do you know how to achieve this goal without writing a separate bash completion script?
EDIT
I think I found something that works. Notice that calling
complete | grep _python_argcomplete

in the bash shell gets completion functions for given Python scripts. In this output, I've found mine
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F _python_argcomplete /absolute/path/to/root/bin/execute.py

thus I've edited my bash script this way
ROOT_DIR="$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"

_my_command_autocomplete() {
    _python_argcomplete ${ROOT_DIR}/bin/execute.py
}

my_command() {
    ${ROOT_DIR}/bin/execute.py "$@"
}

eval "$(register-python-argcomplete ${ROOT_DIR}/bin/execute.py)"
complete -F _my_command_autocomplete my_command

and it worked

As this isn't really a programming question, maybe it would be a better fit for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Okay, and how can I move it there without creating a new question on unix.stackexhange?

I think that you have to create an account there, and just create a new question...

A question about programmable completion is about programming.
